# Split a big KML file by countries

Tags: gratis, kml, geography

I have a KML file containing 5,000,000 places all around the world.

The big quantity of places makes it a pain to use in Google Earth, so I want to split it, one small file per country.

Bonus if tiny countries are grouped together, and huge countries like USA split into states.

Requirements:

- Takes a KML file
- Splits it into areas, I don't have to set up countries definitions myself
- Produces KML files with a prefix+area filename, for instance `mydata_Algeria.kml`
- Free
- Webapps OK, visitors could choose the area they want, and download only that data

If splitting by countries is too difficult, splitting by latitudes/longitudes is OK too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a geographic information system (GIS). A free solution [is QGIS in its current Version 2.18](http://qgis.com/) (Version 3.0 will come out mid-October/November)

However, you would still need to use some programming when you want to meet your goal. In addition you would need a basic understanding of GIS.

A possible workflow without programming would be:

- Load your KML file and a shapefile of the world countries
- (optional): On the world countries file, Create a field which holds a grouping value
- Select A country with the Select tool or with a expression like `"my_field" = 'grouping value'` be aware of the single and double quotation (double indicating a field name, while single is a string/text)
- Use a tool "Select by location" under Vector -> Research tools
- Right click on your *.kml file and choose "save as.."
- In the new window, you can choose the file format and can tick the option "only Save selected features"
- Name the file according to with your standards.

Another way would be to use the graphic modeler of QGIS or the python integration with [pygis](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgisInterface.html)

Comment: Would I have to perform the last 5 steps for each country in the world? A solution that does all countries at once would be the best, especially if it can be called from command line. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul There is certainly a way to automate this process but I would need some time to test it. When QGIS is installed, you have also the osgeo shell installed which comes with ogr2ogr.

Comment: could anyone explain this to me as if I were an 8th grader as even step 1 load kml and "shapefile of the world" are beyond me.  I would know where to get said shapefile or how to install it if I had it.  Also it seems to reject my google location history KML saying it has no data.  Although I am probably just doing it wrong.